# Angular lazy loading - Difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, angular-routing

I was having some issues with Firefox in my angular project that has lazy loading implemented. For some reason in firefox, every service is instantiated twice and I see the "Angular is running in development mode" message twice. Although in chrome I only see it once. (Edge and IE11 also display it only once)

So, is there something new going on in Firefox that causes this issue?

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Doing a lot of Angular development with FF and never seen such behaviour. I suggest cleaning the cache, probably trying the Incognito mode without any extensions to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried everything you said, but no change. I added 2 images, just to show what's going on.